# Error while installing e(fx)clipse plugin on Eclipse Mars.1 IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-mars

I'm trying to install the eclipse plugin e(fx)clipse on my eclipse mars.1(4.5.1). Currently when I go to Help -> Install New Software... , Paste this link (`http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/2.0.0/site`) into the "work with" text box, click on the box to install "e(fx)clipse - install", and click next, I get an erro message stating:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: e(fx)clipse - IDE 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201506111511)
Missing requirement: PDE UI Tooling 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.ui 2.0.0.201506111511) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates 3.4.400' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: e(fx)clipse - IDE 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201506111511)
To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.feature.feature.group [2.0.0.201506111511]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - PDE 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201506111511)
To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.ui [2.0.0.201506111511]
```

I do not know why I would be getting this error message because a couple of weeks ago I installed it on my laptop and it worked just fine. I've googled this and all that comes up are errors like this but only on previous versions of eclipse. Please help and thanks in advance

Here are some screen shots:

[Getting ready to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAMTf.png)

[Installing before it fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWbbT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already follow this guide step-by-step?
https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html#for-the-lazy

I used it on Luna (4.4.1), theoretically should work also on mars...

Comment: I have gone to this website to try this tutorial. But the first step is to download a whole other eclipse program and I don't want to do that. When I installed this on my laptop, I did not need to install anything but the plugin in itself. I would be willing to do this as a last resort, but I've already installed a bunch of other things on my current version of eclipse and would like to continue with this last step of installing the e(fx)clipse plug in.

Comment: Actually I just reinstalled eclipse and it is working now, didn't want to but I gave up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are welcome, anyway you don't need to install the entire eclipse , is enough to install the plugin itself... (If you follow the guide step by step ) In any case the good thing is that you did it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use release 2.1 rather than 2.0 with Mars.1 (4.5.1)

Details [here](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2015/09/04/efxclipse-2-1-0-released/)

Comment: I.ve tried using 2.1 using this,  http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/2.1.0/site and it still does not work.